# Air 2 and streaming mp3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I plan to play more than one MP3 at the same time like multi-track does, I know this will caused a huge increase in memory. Is there a way to stream or buffer live?

If I use it on creating a virtual piano, would it be feasible to embedded 88's or 500MB of MP3 for performance or dynamic load?

Answer (score 0):

Hm...

Stream from files?

It would be possible, but I don't think it would be possible *with AIR API*... I guess a custom library would be usable here... Basically, you would have a class **SoundPlayer**, which would have methods *addSound* and *removeSound*.

Each time *addSound* is called, the path needed (id est the note and instrument needed) is used to initialize a **FileStream** as well as a callback method for a newly created **Sound** instance. The callback would read (buffer) something from the **FileStream** instance, for example, 8192 bytes, or the size of the buffer and write that to the **Sound** buffer.

*removeSound* would simply remove (close, etc...) the instances of both **FileStream** and **Sound** created by *addSound*.

The instances should be stored in some kind of array.

Also, please note that the dynamic-streaming version of **Sound** is VERY undocumented... But this is a sample code to understand how it works:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound(); // new one
mySound.addEventListener("sampleData", getData); // the callback event
var myChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play(); // no arguments for play, channel

// the callback function - it is used to get the new sound buffer
function getData(e:SampleDataEvent):void {
    for (var wi:int = 0; wi < 8192; wi++){
        e.data.writeFloat(Math.random());
    }
}
```

This generates noise (random).

Here's a sawblade waveform. Just because it's fun: (warning: loud)

```
var subWi:Number = 0;
for (var wi:int = 0; wi < 8192; wi++){
    e.data.writeFloat(subWi);
    subWi += 0.01;
    if (subWi >= 1){
        subWi = 0;
    }
}
```

**Note**: with this code you can do a synth as well :D